# Entity Framework ObjectContext.SaveChanges() and class methods

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have more of a theoretical question. If someone could provide me only a link to answer I will be happy as well I just have no idea how to look it up on the internet, so I haven't found an answer.

Lets say I have a class that should check if there is no corrupted data in database. So I have it in normal method etc, with

```
using (var databaseContext = new ExambleDBEntities())
```

Purpose of this method is to check if there is corrupt data - and if there is, to repair it. But it is not question about the code itself, so excuse me for not giving any. It is about... what can I do with data from database.

So I have connection to database, database context is set, query done, I have my first date in let's say "TableName dataSample".

Main question is:

Can I send this "dataSample" to other method inside the same function, where it will be changed and then save changes in main method?

Does the `ObjectContext` keep track of what was taken from database and remember what to save or it MUST be in the same method, under using directive?

I think what I wrote is not clear enough so maybe I'll write some example code:

```
void MainMethod() 
{
  using (var databaseContext = new ExambleDBEntities()) 
  {
    var DatabaseQuery = from... select... ;
    TableName dataSample = DatabaseQuery.First();
    dataSample = CorrectMistakes(dataSample);
    databaseContext.SaveChanges();
  }
}

TableName CorrectMistakes(TableName sample) 
{
  if (somethingWrong)
    sample.money = 0;
  return sample;
}
```

And should I return changed object or can I just edit inside other method?

Sorry for any mistakes, I had really hard time explaining that in English.

Thank you for any help and here is stuff I use in case anyone needs it: Visual Studio 2012, .NET Framework 4.5, MySQL Connector 6.9.4, MySQL for VS 1.2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Sorry, I don't have a link for you, but I just ran a test to be sure and it worked. It shouldn't be too difficult for you to also test this to confirm that it works.

Because you are calling `CorrectMistake()` inside the `using` directive, any changes it makes to the `TableName` object will stay within the current context and be saved when you call `SaveChanges()`.

***Can I send this "dataSample" to other method iside the same function, where it will be changed and then save changes in main method?***

Yes, you can. Try it out!

***Do ObjectContext keep track of what was taken from database and remember what to save or it MUST be in the same method, under using directive?***

Yes and no. It "remembers" while you are in the `using` directive. It doesn't really matter about which method is doing the work, so long as the work is being done while in the `using` block.

***And should I return changed object or can I just edit inside other method?***

It doesn't matter, either will work. Do whatever is most appropriate for your situation. If you are just making a change to one of the object's properties, then it probably makes more sense to edit inside the method.

Consider this simple example:

```
private void ChangeObject(object obj)
{
    if (something)
        obj.Name = "New name";
}

using (var db = new Context())
{
    var obj = db.Objects.First();
    ChangeObject(obj);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

this is equivalent to:

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    var obj = db.Objects.First();

    if (something)
        obj.Name = "New name";

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```